# What causes the charges in conductor to move towards lower potential terminal of cell

Tags: electricity, electric-fields, charge, potential, conductors

Whenever a conductor is connected to a cell,what causes the conventional positivecharges inside it to move towards the lower potential level of cell..
My question is whether the charges experience a force due to electric field or all the positive charges in conductor gain higher potential energy and hence flow towards lower potential terminal of cell

Comment: Why do you ask an "either/or" question? Your options are the same thing as each other. You should review the definition of potential energy.

Comment: You've asked this same question 3 times in the past couple days. You should still read the other question I linked. When you understand the answer, you'll see that it answers your question as well. If you don't understand the answer, you should say what about it isn't clear and ask for an explanation of that specific issue.

Comment: Summary: The potential is defined by ${\bf E}=-{\bf \nabla} V$. That means that the field (which exerts a force on the charge carriers) is what makes the potential be higher in one place or another. Or conversely, that the potential is a kind of summary of where the field points to.